Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly that could not be resolved - Delete Duplicates
I have been reading a report from a test run that is shown below. I suspect the issue is that I have one too many solutions according to Visual Studio 2019. If it's from creating one too many projects, how do I delete the duplicates?
Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly that could not be resolved
I was expecting to know how the duplicates are handled by using information from this article.
